# Django admin integer field with '+' '-' on either side to increment/decrement value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Im stuck in a client's requirement. He wants to have a field in django admin panel like the screenshot I have attached
[image: screenshot]

I have a field in my model
landing_page_btn_text_size = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("Button Text Size"), max_length=255, default="20px")

Now he want if i click '-' it subtracts 1 from the value and if '+' it adds 1 to the value.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't that be an integer field with an added `px` in the representation then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django automatically includes this on an IntegerField. One way to include this, is to add in px to the verbose_name and change the model it to an IntegerField.